# MoinMoin ACL on certain pages

Tags: python, moinmoin

We are using MoinMoin as a wiki for our applications. We would like to open are set of pages to the public access. How would I do that ?

Can I set a public access on some pages in the configuration file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to set a page 'read only for un-authentificated users' :

1. edit the configuration file **wikiconfig.py** with

   acl_rights_before = u"AnAdminAccount:read,write,delete,revert,admin"

   acl_rights_default = u"AnAdminAccount:read,write,delete,revert,admin"
2. Add on top of the wiki page that you would like to open for the public :

   `#acl MyUserName:read,write,admin,revert,delete All:read`

Answer (score 0):

read HelpOnAccessControlLists wiki page.

you can set ACLs at the top of the page content.